# how to convert string to float while plot the date with Python matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, series

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o41bg.png)

I want to draw the close price (y-axis) and date (x-axis) with python, but the error shows that I need to convert date from string to float.

Here is coding:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import datetime

from pandas import DataFrame, Series

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vicky/Desktop/pythontest/T1706dailyrecord.csv')

df.columns = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(df)

plt.plot(df[1], df[3])
```

Comment: what is df1,  can show your code,

Comment: Put your coding part in Code Sample format, to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

I think you need parameter `parse_dates` for convert column to `datetime` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vicky/Desktop/pythontest/T1706dailyrecord.csv', parse_dates=[0])
```

Or:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Vicky/Desktop/pythontest/T1706dailyrecord.csv',parse_dates=['Date'])
```

Also `df.columns = [1,2,3,4,5]` is not necessary, for select use: `df['Date']` and `df['Close']`:

```
plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Close'])
```

Also is possible use [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df.plot(x='Date', y='Close')
```